# Android dynamically change layout size

Tags: android, android-framelayout

I would like a square `FrameLayout` that fills the width of it's parent and whose height matches it's width. I've tried adding an **addOnLayoutChangeListener** to the layout, but I can't call `requestLayout` on it from inside that so I have no way to tell it to resize.

What can I do to make it's height equal to it's width at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution is extend `FrameLayout`

```
public class SquareFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
            // or you can use this if you want the square to use width as it basis
             super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec); 
    }
}
```

use it your layout like below

```
 <your.package.SquareFrameLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
    ......>
        <!-- other child views -->
 </your.package.SquareFrameLayout>
```

Comment: I was hoping not to override the layout, but you're probably right, it's the simplest way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After you obtain your view just do the following

```
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = view.getLayoutParams();
    Display display = ((AppCompatActivity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int screenWidth = size.X;
    lp.height = screenWidth;
    view.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: I'm going to be adding the view programmatically because it's going to change. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: nice answer, Logic. It's going to come in handy